# Select based on numeric difference

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sql

I have a database table that holds order information and saves the current gold price (world price) automatically at the time of entry.

If I look back on the table, and the saved gold price has a difference with the current gold price of +100, O want to show that in a report.

How would I write the MySQL query to do this? I know how to do datediffs but not numeric values.

Example:

```
select * from table where saved_price < current_price - 100
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Abs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) if the sign of the difference doesn't matter:

```
select * from table where abs(saved_price - current_price) > 100
```

If the sign is interesting, your suggested approach is fine. I'd write it like this, but use the way you think is the most read- and understandable:

```
select * from table where (current_price - saved_price) >= 100
```